# Visual Basic webbrowser click submit without ID

Tags: c#

Hi today i decided to make a message sender program for a game online, i made the login part succefull , but now i need to work without ID's  , the thing is this, the page is a game, so after i login it uses flash player or java, and i need to press a button inside that game to send invites ... can someone help me to get that button click ?

i leave u image here

http://i.snag.gy/H5xsC.jpg

i need to press that with code in visual basic but i cant get any id to it

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate("http://site.ru/login.html");
wb.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", "username");
wb.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "password");
wb.Document.GetElementById("submitButton").InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: Hi, i made this already, but i made the post for another thing ... i need to press that invite friends button ... i leave a pic, hope u reply back :)